# How to remove decimal from Year, in google chart API?

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have implemented the google chart API in an Admin panel.
All have successfully worked, the data is successfully loaded in the jQuery.

Here's my code:-

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
    /*--------This code is for Line Chart ----------*/          
    var optionsLine = {
      title: 'User Enrollment Statistics',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };          

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>ajax-graph-user-join",
        data: {'type':'yearwise','year':'','month':''},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var dataArr = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                var ar = [data[i].Year, data[i].User];
                dataArr.push(ar);
            }
            console.log(dataArr);
            var dataLine = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArr);
            var chartLine = new google.visualization.LineChart($("#lineChart")[0]);
            chartLine.draw(dataLine, optionsLine);
        },
        failure: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        }
    });
}
```

Now, to explain my issue, I am sharing the image:-
[image]

As you can see, the years(along the x-axis) is showing as decimals with zero and .5

I want the Years to be shown as integer only, and without the comma i.e. 2,014.

**How can I do that?**

### Edit:-

After been suggested to put `hAxis: {format: '0000'}` in the `optionsLine`, my graph is coming like this:
[image]

Two `2015` and two `2016`

Comment: I think you can manage that from your PHP code

Answer (score 5):

use the `hAxis.format` [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)

```
var optionsLine = {
  title: 'User Enrollment Statistics',
  curveType: 'function',
  legend: { position: 'bottom' },
  hAxis: {
    format: '0000'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

> hAxis: {
>                       gridlines: {
>                           color:'transparent'
>                       },
>                       format:'0'
>                   },

It will work!

Comment: Please be more precise. Show where do we need to add this parameter. It's very unclear and unhelpful

Answer (score 0):

if the chart is not doing any conversion following can make it to int

```
  var ar = [data[i].Year, data[i].User];
```

replace with

```
    var ar = [parseInt(data[i].Year), data[i].User];
```

Also in top optionsLine add following option

```
var optionsLine = {
title: 'User Enrollment Statistics',
curveType: 'function',
legend: { position: 'bottom' },
 vAxis: {format: '0'},
 hAxis: {format: '0000'}
};
```

Comment: whats the output of console.log(dataArr); ? is it right ?